# When Internet Explorer 8 opens then WPF application UI freezes

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer-8

System Information:
Win 7 32-Bit,
Internet Explorer 8,
.Net Framework 4 Installed.

Issue that;
When Internet Explorer 8 opens then WPF application UI freezes, application continues to work on the taskmanager without not-respond or have any exception. WPF window gets non-clickable and focusable UI.